# WCF - Service Reference not be created

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, service

My WCF service was working correctly and then all of sudden it stop working.  I don't think I changed anything with the configuration.

The WCF service is hosted by a windows service.

What is weird is when I add the service reference, it will identify the contract and all the methods exposed. But if I go to a browser I get a 404 error and the compiler is not creating the service. I have deleted and tried to re-add the reference with no luck

Also, my deployed application is still able to access the wcf service.

Question 1:
In a WCF windows service, should I be able to see the wsdl inside a browser (http://localhost:8080/MaestroService/mex). In IE, I am getting 400 Bad Request.  I am assuming that this is the root of the problem.

Question 2:
Is there something else?

**App.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="NewBinding0" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
<serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="metadataAndDebug">
    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
  </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="metadataAndDebug" name="MaestroServiceLibrary.MaestroService">
    <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0"
      name="basicHttp" contract="MaestroServiceLibrary.IMaestroService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8888/MaestroService" binding="netTcpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="" name="netTcpBinding" contract="MaestroServiceLibrary.IMaestroService" />
    <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/MaestroService" binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="" name="netNamedPipeBinding" contract="MaestroServiceLibrary.IMaestroService" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/MaestroService" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

**Errors Compiling:**

```
Custom tool error: Failed to generate code for the service reference 'MaestroService'.  Please check other error and warning messages for details.

Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding


Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
```

XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:portType[@name='IMaestroService']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@name='basicHttp']

**Update**

I turned on the tracing and I saw this:
The message with To 'http://localhost:8080/MaestroService/mex/mex' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.  I will update this question if I figure it out.

**Update V2**

I went to another project inside the same solution.  I was able to add the service there with no problems.  I notice I was using 3.5 in the console app vs 4.0 in the wpf browser app.  When I came back to report this, I noticed in my last update that it had /mex/mex even though I put http://localhost:8080/MaestroService/mex in the url .  I tried just http://localhost:8080/MaestroService and it work!!!

In the end, I did end up using Migual Castro technique [here](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=122), where you create the conracts and the proxy. Which was good to see how it really works and what VS is doing.  But it would be good to have that day and a half back.

thanks for the suggestions everyone.

Comment: "I don't think I changed anything with the configuration. " - that's usually the cause of things stopping working....

Comment: @Mitch.  Yah. :( I try not to touch it but I cant be 100% sure.  But I know I have not touched the configuration of the production copy which I am getting the same results

Answer (score 0):

You are running as a windows service.

A windows service runs in the security context of a user account.

If the password of the user account changes or expires, the service does not run.

The first thing that you should check is: Is the service running.

Comment: The service is running. If it was not I would get the following adding the reference:  Unable to connect to the remote server.  And  no response in IE

Comment: Could it be the empty binding configuration?

Comment: I gave up on trying to figure out why all of a sudden I was not able to add a service reference.  I ended following the technique used here http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=122.  It seems like a much cleaner implementation then adding a service reference

Comment: That is actually the method that we use :)